# Error el subir mi archivo de fpdf a la web y local funciona bien

Tags: php, mysql

A lo mejor el tema sea viejo, pero no he podido resolverlo.

El problema que tengo es con una ficha en local. Me la carga, todo bien, me hace las consultas, sale perfecto, pero al subirla al servidor, no muestra nada.

La he obligado a mostrar el error, si me pueden ayudar y orientar, es la primera vez que trabajo con esta librería, he leído en algunos foros que ya está obsoleta, pero me parece que es la que tiene menos peso en cuanto a todos los archivos que requiere para generar el pdf.

De igual forma, si conocen alguna que no sea tan complicada, probé que *tcpdf* y me dio muchos errores aparte requiere casi 14 mb de librería, probé *html2pdf* y tampoco me gustó el resultado.

He leído sobre *mpfd* pero aún no la pruebo. y sale lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: error FPDF: No page has been added
> yet in /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
> /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php(1447): FPDF->Error('No page has
> bee...') #1 /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php(924): FPDF->_out('q
> 113.43 0 0 14...') #2 /home/public_html/demo/Detalleim.php(113): FPDF->Image('img/cabecera/ba...', 17, 5, 40.014769230769) #3 {main}
> thrown in /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271

El código no lo muestra muy bien, subí el archivo a drive lo pueden bajar alli. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5ghAKLXT_12ynJiCzdC1tk4-ShgP9SF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yo utilizo esa libreria actualmente (FPDF), si queres te adjunto un ejemplo de como lo hice, porque no veo que tengas algun error. Me funciona bien en localhost y en mi servidor. Saludos.

Comment: saludos buenos dias franco agradecido por la respuesta, a ver te cuento realice una ficha que me consulta varias tablas en mysql y al cargar las tablas me muestra ese error, si tienes alguna que me puedas facilitar para orientarme te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, disculpe la demora, aqui le adjunto un ejemplo de la manera en que utilice la libreria FPDF que incluye consultas a la base de datos tambien. Lo que realizo aqui es generar un listado de jugadores de un equipo 'X' seleccionado anterioirmente. Espero le sea de utilidad. Saludos cordiales,

```js
require_once 'funciones.php';
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
//include 'menu.php';
$link = conectarse();
session_start();
ob_start();
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$equipo = $_SESSION['equipo'];
$categoria= $_SESSION['categoria'];

//$equipo = $_GET['equipo'];
//echo 'hola'.$categoria;
//$numero=0;

//Conecto a la base de datos
$enlace = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
 
mysql_select_db("edwin", $enlace);
//Consulta la tabla productos solicitando todos los productos
 
class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Header() {
        $this->Image('images/icono.png', 5, 0, 38);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
        $this->Cell(25);
        $this->Cell(140, 10, utf8_decode('NEWCOM RÍO CUARTO 2019'), 0, 0, 'C');
        $this->Image('images/newcom/evento-newcom.png', 170, 2, 30);
        $this->Ln(25);
    }

    function Footer() {
        
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Pagina ' . $this->PageNo(), 0, 0, 'C');
    }

}

if ($categoria=='TODOS') {
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT persona.pers_id, persona.pers_nomb, persona.pers_apel, persona.pers_dni, persona.pers_tel, persona.pers_fecnac, categoria.cate_nomb, persona.pers_sexo, persona.pers_email, persona.pers_comp_pago, equipo.equi_nombre FROM equipo_has_persona INNER JOIN persona ON equipo_has_persona.persona_pers_id=persona.pers_id INNER JOIN categoria ON persona.cate_id=categoria.cate_id INNER JOIN equipo ON equipo_has_persona.equipo_equi_id=equipo.equi_id WHERE (equipo.equi_nombre='$equipo') ORDER BY persona.pers_apel ASC", $link);
    
}else{
    $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT persona.pers_id, persona.pers_nomb, persona.pers_apel, persona.pers_dni, persona.pers_tel, persona.pers_fecnac, categoria.cate_nomb, persona.pers_sexo, persona.pers_email, persona.pers_comp_pago, equipo.equi_nombre FROM equipo_has_persona INNER JOIN persona ON equipo_has_persona.persona_pers_id=persona.pers_id INNER JOIN categoria ON persona.cate_id=categoria.cate_id INNER JOIN equipo ON equipo_has_persona.equipo_equi_id=equipo.equi_id WHERE ((equipo.equi_nombre='$equipo') AND (categoria.cate_nomb='$categoria')) ORDER BY persona.pers_apel ASC", $link);
    }


//Instaciamos la clase para genrear el documento pdf
$pdf=new PDF();
 
//Agregamos la primera pagina al documento pdf
$pdf->AddPage();
 

 
//Creamos las celdas para los titulo de cada columna y le asignamos un fondo gris y el tipo de letra
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(190, 6, utf8_decode('LISTADO DE JUGADORES NEWCOM RÍO CUARTO 2019  -  Equipo:'.$equipo.'   -   Categoría:'.$categoria), 1, 1, 'C'); //RENGLON PARA FECHA Y ESTADO
$pdf->Cell(190, 6, '', 1, 1, 'C'); //renglon en blanco
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'Nro.',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,6,'Apellido y Nombre',1,0,'C',1);
//$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Apellido',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'DNI',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Fecha Nac.',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Telefono',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Sexo',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode('Categoría'),1,0,'C',1);
 
$pdf->Ln(10);
 
//Comienzo a crear las filas de productos según la consulta mysql con los nombres de la base de datos
 
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    $numero = $numero + 1;
    $nombre = $fila['pers_nomb'];
    $apellido = $fila['pers_apel'];
    $dni=$fila['pers_dni'];
    $fechanac= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fila['pers_fecnac']));
    $telefono=$fila['pers_tel'];
    $sexo=$fila['pers_sexo'];
    $email=$fila['cate_nomb'];
 
   //125 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $pdf->Cell(10,5,$numero,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$apellido.' '.$nombre,1,0,'L',0);
    //$pdf->Cell(30,5,$apellido,1,0,'L',0);     
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$dni,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$fechanac,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$telefono,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$sexo,1,0,'L',0);
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$email,1,0,'L',0);
//Muestro la iamgen dentro de la celda GetX y GetY dan las coordenadas actuales de la fila
 
     //$pdf->Cell( 30, 15, $pdf->Image($imagen, $pdf->GetX()+5, $pdf->GetY()+3, 20), 1, 0, 'C', false );
 
$pdf->Ln(5);
 
}
 
mysql_close($enlace);
 
//Mostramos el documento pdf
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

no sé si es oportuno...y a tiempo...pero para cualquiera en general que le pasé...en el local Host funciona bien...por qué la comparación con las rayas invertidas pues como que no las hace...ya qué en el computador da la misma para generar una ruta de qué costado estela linea invertida...pero al subirla al servidor...la cosa cambia y sí...si la raya invertida està asi "" en cualquier parte del codigo, genera el error...por lo general el 505...si revusas el codigo y cambuasla barra invertida a:"/" sé soluciona a la perfección...esoeri les sirva este comentario

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/346110)

Answer (score 0):

Me paso que cuando lo corria en windows funcionaba pero a la hora de subirlo a produccion en distro de linux debian 11 no funcionaba ese modulo en especifico, debia de lanzarme un alert en la vista que menciona que ha sido creado, pero eso no pasaba y solo generaba una vista en blanco como la que muestras, ahora quiero hacer enfasis en esta parte en especifico ya que se le esta diciendo a la clase que haga un archivo temporal con output el cual crea un archivo temporal en el server que sera pasado a travez de la url entonces quiere decir que si no se imprime es porque ni siquiera lo esta creando para darle salida de modo que me puse a ver los permisos en windows y tenia totalidad de permisos el que importa mas es que tenga el de ejecucion ya que va a comportarse como un script que genera mas archivos de modo que si este archivo no tiene los permisos dados en tu server no va a poder generar este archivo temporal que incluso pude ver que se genera en tiempo de ejecucion en SO windows mas no en linux y ahi empece a indagar a lo que me llevo a ceder permisos al grupo de usuarios y apache para que pueda generarse

$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');

$pdf -> Output($nombreArchivo, 'F', true);

ahora bien si es error de programacion pueden ir debuggeando con var_dump o echo seguido de un die(); para que se detenga en ese bloque en especifico y ver que esta trayendo.

Cuando cambias de un server a otro siempre checa la parte de permisos si es que en windows funciona pero no en el server de produccion mayormente con distribucion de linux, espero te sirva